# How to reuse functions in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

We are having some issue here. There are two python files parent and child in same folder. I want to reuse the function("sum") of parent in child, instead of copying the same function("sum") into child. Please refer the image below.

child.py

```
def add(a,b):
    sum(a,b)
```

parent.py

```
import child
def sum(a,b):
    print(a+b)
def main():
    child.add(1,2) # Prints 3
```

Comment: Parent depends from child, and child depends from parent. This is a circular dependency, which is not a quite good idea in general.

Comment: You shouldn't want to do this, this creates a circular import where `child.py` needs `parent.py` and vice-versa.

Comment: The issues you are having are exactly why this is a bad design.  Reconsider why you are doing it like this.

Answer (score 3):

Put `sum()` in a third module that is imported by both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use imports:

In `child.py`

```
from parent import sum
```

Now you can use the `sum` function as you want.

Having said that, it looks like this question has multiple issues that will be a debugging nightmare

1. Circular imports
2. Overriding builtin functions

Consider reading a basic tutorial on Python imports and builtin functions.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use it as:-**

In child.py use:-

```
from parent import sum
def add(a,b):
    sum(a,b)

add(3,10) #output 13 as expected
```